# Problems scrolling in Excel Online with Selenium

Tags: excel, selenium, scroll, sendkeys

I'm running a test to verify the contents of a file in Office 365. The file is a .xlsx file. I can open the file in excel online and verify the contents of the spreadsheet up to a point - unfortunately it's a large file and I need to scroll down to make more data visible.  I've tried the following:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1200)", "");
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

but neither seem to do anything. Can anyone suggest something else? Is there a way I can drag the scroll bar downwards?

EDIT:

Browser is Firefox.

I should have been more clear about the 'file' - it's an attachment which is uploaded to an Outlook group in Office365. I open it simply by clicking on a link. This then opens in Excel Online which displays as a frame on top of the normal Outlook screen.

By using:

> `Browser.getTopBrowser(driver);`
>   `driver.switchTo().frame("CollabOfficeDocumentBody");` 
>   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("class"));` 
>   I can find the contents of individual cells, but only to a certain point (54 rows down I think).

I'm not sure if this answers your questions...

Comment: What browser is this? What plugin is used to open the file? And how? Please show us more code.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Problem solved - clicking on the last element I could find automatically scrolled to that cell on the spreadsheet. A rather obvious solution which took me 24 hours to come to!